# yarn ignores npmregistryserver entry

Tags: yarn-v2

I'm using verdaccio on a local docker instance for development purposes of my own scoped Nodejs packages. In .yarnrc.yml I'm using two IP addresses for the scoped packages: One for building on localhost and one for building inside Docker, but only one will be active at a time.

```
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.3.1.cjs
nodeLinker: node-modules

enableGlobalCache: false
enableMirror: false

npmScopes:
  mycompany:
#    npmRegistryServer: "http://172.23.0.2:4873"
    npmRegistryServer: "http://127.0.0.1:4873"

unsafeHttpWhitelist:
  - "172.23.0.2"
  - "127.0.0.1"
  - "localhost"
```

When switching between the entries, yarn frequently doesn't use the active entry. Instead, it uses the previously activated and now inactive IP address. yarn should use 127.0.0.1, but uses 172.23.0.2.

```
➤ YN0013: │ @mycompany/service@npm:0.1.0::__archiveUrl=http%3A%2F%2F172.23.0.2%3A4873%2F%40mycompany%252fservice%2F-%2Fservice-0.1.0.tgz can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote server
```

Where does yarn get this information from?

Global cache and mirror are disabled. The DNS cache is flushed. Cleaned yarn cache and deleted yarn.lock.